# How to prevent a for loop from stopping?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

In my for loop, when the if statements are both true, it does what it is supposed to and then it just ends and doesn't continue through the whole loop. I tried using a `continue` statement after the counters buy and sell. It worked when storing the sums of the variables, but then I got an error on the return variable that says NoneType object of builtins module.

If I leave out the continue statement, it just stores the first price it matches the if statement, but it breaks and stop summing up the other prices that match those statements.

I know the issue is that it breaks from the for loop after the addition of the counters, maybe is the return badly indented?

```
buy = 0
sell = 0
def checking(x,y):
    for i in range (17):
        if x[i]>x[i-1]:
            if y[i] >y[i-1]:
                global buy, sell
                buy += y[i]
                try:
                    sell +=y[i+1]
                except:
                    sell +=y[i]

                continue
                return sell-buy

gains = checking(volume,close)

gains
```

I need to make a function that reads 2 dataframes, one is the volume of a stock and the other one is the close price. I want the function to check if the volume from today is greater than the one from yesterday, and if that's true then it enters another if statement, asking if the close price of today is greater than the one from yesterday. If this one is also true then it store and sums the prices of those days in the "buy" variable and store and sums the prices of the day after [i+1] in the "sell" variable. At the end it returns the difference between this two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the indentation of the return statement was incorrect. Here's the fixed code:

```
buy = 0
sell = 0
def checking(x,y):
    for i in range (17):
        if x[i]>x[i-1]:
            if y[i] >y[i-1]:
                global buy, sell
                buy += y[i]
                try:
                    sell +=y[i+1]
                except:
                    sell +=y[i]

    return sell-buy

gains = checking(volume,close)
```

Comment: @GuillermoCampollo If an answer solves your problem, you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Tried to upvote it but it tells me i need 15 reputation, whatever that means. But i already accepted it, thanks again

Comment: @GuillermoCampollo See [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and [Upvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0):

```
buy = 0
sell = 0
def checking(x,y):
    for i in range (17):
        if x[i]>x[i-1]:
            if y[i] >y[i-1]:
                global buy, sell
                buy += y[i]
                try:
                    sell +=y[i+1]
                except:
                    sell +=y[i]


    return sell-buy

gains = checking(volume,close)
```